# Choosing Random number in java

Tags: java

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

I've tried it and it is working but still confuse about the logic used, I want to know that why we add min value to random number in end?

Comment: If you don't add a value the minimum of `nextInt` is 0. If you add 4 for example, the minimum become 4.

Answer (score 1):

`Random#nextInt(n)` returns a random integer between 0 and `n-1`. By adding `min` to the return value of `r.nextInt(max - min + 1)`, the result is a random integer between `min` and `max` (inclusive).

The following table might clarify the logic a bit:

```
     Expression                 |  smallest value  |  largest value
--------------------------------+------------------+-------------------
r.nextInt(max - min + 1)        |       0          |    max - min
--------------------------------+------------------+-------------------
r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min  |      min         |       max
--------------------------------+------------------+-------------------
```